# Json.NET and generic dictionaries

Tags: c#, collections, json.net

It seems impossible to (de-)serialize a *generic* dictionary using Json.NET out of the box.

```
class KeyClass
{
    public KeyClass(string p1, string p2) { prop1 = p1; prop2 = p2;}
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}

class ValueClass
{
    public ValueClass(string pa, string pb) { propA = pa; propB = pb;}
    public string propA { get; set; }
    public string propB { get; set; }
}

...

Dictionary<KeyClass, ValueClass> d = new Dictionary<KeyClass, ValueClass>();
d.Add(new KeyClass("k1", "k2"), new ValueClass("v1", "v2"));
d.Add(new KeyClass("k3", "k4"), new ValueClass("v3", "v4"));
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

returns

```
{"ConsoleApplication1.KeyClass":{"propA":"v1","propB":"v2"},
 "ConsoleApplication1.KeyClass":{"propA":"v3","propB":"v4"}}
```

where I expected something like:

```
{{"prop1":"k1","prop2":"k2"}:{"propA":"v1","propB":"v2"},
 {"prop1":"k3","prop2":"k4"}:{"propA":"v3","propB":"v4"}}
```

So `ToString()` is called on the key (KeyClass). (an override that generates json doesn't help: escapes the json and just doesn't feel right).

Is it possible to write a CustomCreationConverter for this case?
Is this a *hard* limitation of json.NET?
If so, do other libraries support this?

Comment: Curious, why aren't you doing "{ "key" : "val" }, that's how maps are supposed to be represented in JSON, last I checked

Comment: @casperOne: these 2 classes are just examples, the ones I try to 'jsonify' contain a lot more properties: the KeyClass in my case is an object representing a Language, the ValueClass an object representing a label in that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not supported in JSON, it has little to do with JSON.NET: a "dictionary" (it's called an object in JSON) **must** always have string keys. Just look at the [JSON specs](http://www.json.org/).

What JSON.NET is doing here is a "right" way to handle a C# dictionary (another is to throw an error).

Note that JavaScript (of which JSON is a very restricted subset) also does not allow your proposed syntax.

One way to serialize a generic dictionary (or non-generic dictionaries with non-string keys) is by serializing it as a list of key-value-pairs, e.g.,

```
[ { "key": {"prop1":"k1","prop2":"k2"}, "value": {"propA":"v1","propB":"v2"} },
  { "key": {"prop1":"k3","prop2":"k4"}, "value": {"propA":"v3","propB":"v4"} } ]
```

How to that with JSON.NET is another matter, but if it's possible you can try to expose the dictionary as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<X,Y>>`.